# ¿Como obtener o guardar los resultados html de una geolocalización?

Tags: html, geolocalización

Tengo un servidor web remoto, lo que quiero realizar, es que a traves del siguiente codigo que voy a poner mas abajo, pueda obtener los resultados, en este caso es una geolocalizacion, es decir quiero que los resultados de la geolocalizacion se guarden ya sea en un txt o en una base de datos, que yo pueda ver desde donde se han conectado, tener un registro. Muchas Gracias.
Se que hay que darle permisos, pero no importa eso, quiero saber en si como puedo que me quede registradas las coordenadas de donde se realiza la consulta, o accion. Muchas gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme.
Mi codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <p> Click para ingresar a la página. </p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Aceptar </button>

  <p id="demo"> </p>

    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");

      function getLocation() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        } else {

          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

      }

      function showPosition(position) {

        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +

          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A partir de Chrome 50 las conexiones no seguras (HTTP) entre cliente-servidor, NO se permite el acceso a la geolocalización del dispositivo, necesitarás un certificado SSL para que los datos se transmitan encriptados, y así conseguir una conexión segura (HTTPS).

Comment: Hola, si me he informado sobre eso, igualmente estoy aprendiendo y lo realizo a travez de firefox, lo unico no se que recurso utilizar para que me quede un registro, ya sea base de datos, o archivo de texto, donde posea persistencia. Gracias

Comment: Pareciera que no has investigado mucho por tu cuenta antes de preguntar. Te recomiendo estos links para que aprendas a hacerlo en php, http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php , https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp , https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Bien dicen los otros comentarios pero bueno, aquí está un código en php que te permite obtener nadamás la IP, espero te sirva de algo:

```
<?php
   $ipaccess = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
   $ipcompartido =  $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
   $ipproxy = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
   $fichero = "IPs.txt";
   $handle = fopen($fichero, "a");
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
   fwrite($handle, $ipaccess);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
   fwrite($handle, $ipcompartido);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
   fwrite($handle, $ipproxy);
   fclose($handle);
?>
```

Evidentemente además de una función que llame al php, tendrás que tener creado el archivo IPs.txt (aunque puedes modificar el nombre) en el mismo directorio donde el php.

Y una recomendación (por experiencia jaja) algunos servidores no deja subir ficheros vacíos así que en IPs.txt agrega un punto o un caracter para solucionar esto y ya lo demás se irá escribiendo debajo.